# launchimage module 2.1: Validation failed for module 'launchimage' with error: ipad

Tags: trigger.io, forge, launchimage

trigger.io;

after upgrading to launchimage module 2.1 I just get error 'Validation failed for module 'launchimage' with error: ipad'

any ideas what this error is about?

the old docs were really good, providing a very clear spec: 
http://legacy-docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/launchimage.html

the new docs for version 2.1 are totally opaque:
https://trigger.io/modules/launchimage/current/docs/index.html

n.b. apologies for posting this to SO - its basically a trigger.io support request

Answer (score 2):

I believe this error indicates that you haven't filled out the public lauchimage module in its entirety like [this.](http://screencloud.net/v/bzcV)

If you are packaging the app as `universal` I think you'll need to have all the fields filled out as Trigger then prepares your ipa for all platforms(iPad and iPhone).

Answer (score 0):

I found its easiest to just ignore the docs, create a demo project and use the trigger.io toolkit app to generate example config - prevents toolkit app from overwriting existing app config.

have to say I'd way prefer to work from the documentation and edit json config files directly rather than spend my time going through tedious point-and-click config..

Comment: I usually just keep the config files open in a sublime tab and then make any necessary edits there when I need to.